# Ajax response is getting but not posting on the PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to retrive the data got from jquery to php via ajax.

My code to start up a modal window

```
<a href='javascript:void(0):' data-id={$row['customer_id']} class='btn small bg-blue-alt tooltip-button modal-customeredit' data-placement='top' title='Edit'><i class='glyph-icon icon-edit' ></i>
```

here am getting id from main page.and opening a modal pop up.
modal script as follows.

```
$( ".modal-customeredit" ).click(function() {
    var myGroupId = $(this).attr('data-id'); // data-id
    data = {'id':myGroupId };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "left.inc.php",
        data: data, // data retrieve on server-side ($_POST['id'])
        success:function(response){
            $( "#modal-customeredit" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                minWidth: 700,
                minHeight: 200,
                dialogClass: "modal-dialog",
                show: "fadeIn"
            });
            alert('done');
            alert(response); //do the rest of operations.
        }

    });

my form code is for modal:
            <!-- Customer Edit -->
<div class="hide" id="modal-customeredit" title="Edit Customer Info">
<div class="pad10A">
<h3>Update Customer Info</h3>
<p class="font-gray-dark"> Fides Admin uses colors & styles from both the default theme color schemes and the included core color helpers. </p>
<div class="divider"></div>
<form id="customer-edit" action="" class="col-md-12 center-margin" method="">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-label col-md-3">
<label for="name">
  Name:
  <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-input col-md-9">
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-label col-md-3">
<label for="details">
  Details :
  <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-input col-md-9">
<input id="details" placeholder="Details" name="details" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-label col-md-3">
<label for="domain">
  Domain :
  <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-input col-md-9">
<input id="domain" placeholder="Domain" name="domain" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-label col-md-3">
<label for="vertical">
  Vertical :
  <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-input col-md-9">
<input id="vertical" placeholder="Vertical" name="vertical" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-label col-md-3">
<label for="taxanomy">
  Taxanomy :
  <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-input col-md-9">
<input id="taxanomy" placeholder="Taxanomy" name="taxanomy" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
</div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-input col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn medium primary-bg radius-all-4" id="customer-edit-valid" onclick="javascript:$('#customer-edit').parsley( 'validate' );" title="Validate!"><span class="button-content">Submit</span></a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($pfile=="customer-screen.php") { ?>
```

The problem i face is i got response from ajax.which display the exact id i want.
But when i try in php as

```
<?php $id=$_POST['id']; 
echo $id; ?>
```

I was not able to echo the id in php file.But ajax display in the response.Hope i am conveying the question properly.If u help it will be really appreciated.If you have doubts about my question.Please comment let me expalin.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If ajax is displaying the response in the alert, then everything is working.

Comment: I assume the missing brace and parenthesis at the end are just a copying error.

Comment: @barmar i am not getting the id variable in php page

Answer (score -1):

The data you're posting is in JSON format, not URL format. The data should be 'id=' + myGroupId.

Comment: `$.ajax` automatically converts an object to URL format.